# Core Data EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

Tags: ios, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsmanagedobject

I have multiple crash reports that point to the following:

```
Thread : Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x18c7fba0
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x38665a36 OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32Barrier + 13
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3805694b realizeClass(objc_class*) + 78
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38058797 lookUpImpOrForward + 74
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3805102b _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 34
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x38050df9 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 24
5  CoreData                       0x2da7b5bb -[_NSFaultingMutableSet copyWithZone:] + 238
6  MyApp                          0x0027226f -[Zoo getSortedCats] (Zoo.m:63)
7  MyApp                          0x00286955 -[BlockExecutionOperation main] (BlockExecutionOperation.m:30)
8  Foundation                     0x2e627aa5 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 772
9  Foundation                     0x2e6cb96d __NSOQSchedule_f + 60
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x3853e4b7 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 110
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3853f7d9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 224
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3853f9c5 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x38669dff _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

The getSortedCats method looks like this:

```
- (NSArray *)getSortedCats {
    NSSet* cats = [self.cats copy]; //this is line 63, where the crash occurs

    //do some sorting

    return sortedCats;

}
```

And Zoo is an NSManagedObject subclass with a cats property:

```
@property (atomic, retain) NSSet *cats;
```

So why the crash on the self.cats line? What does this error mean? How to avoid? It only happens once in a while, and is not reproducible.

Comment: Why are you copying your cats?

Comment: Sounds like a dangling pointer. Try to run your project with Instruments' Zombies template to track the lifecycle of `cats`.

Comment: @duci9y maybe because it's a copycat! :)

Comment: Does that object actually belong to that operation queue? Core Data objects are not thread safe; they require thread confinement. It looks like you're dispatching a block directly to call `getSortedCats`; have you possibly disobeyed the rules related to thread-safe Core Data usage?

Answer (score 4):

Peculiarity with Core Data. Sending `copy` would just return another `NSFaultingMutableSet`, and Core Data is too buggy to do that right.

Replace it with `[NSSet setWithSet:self.cats]` and you'd face lesser errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will up vote for now and mark correct later if the crashing goes away.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I still don't really understand why this is necessary.